# Creating a new corpus with NLTK

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, corpus

I reckoned that often the answer to my title is to go and read the documentations, but I ran through the [NLTK book](http://www.nltk.org/book) but it doesn't give the answer. I'm kind of new to Python.

I have a bunch of `.txt` files and I want to be able to use the corpus functions that NLTK provides for the corpus `nltk_data`.

I've tried `PlaintextCorpusReader` but I couldn't get further than:

```
>>>import nltk
>>>from nltk.corpus import PlaintextCorpusReader
>>>corpus_root = './'
>>>newcorpus = PlaintextCorpusReader(corpus_root, '.*')
>>>newcorpus.words()
```

How do I segment the `newcorpus` sentences using punkt? I tried using the punkt functions but the punkt functions couldn't read `PlaintextCorpusReader` class?

Can you also lead me to how I can write the segmented data into text files?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I think the `PlaintextCorpusReader` already segments the input with a punkt tokenizer, at least if your input language is english.

[PlainTextCorpusReader's constructor](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.corpus.reader.html#nltk.corpus.reader.plaintext.PlaintextCorpusReader)

```
def __init__(self, root, fileids,
             word_tokenizer=WordPunctTokenizer(),
             sent_tokenizer=nltk.data.LazyLoader(
                 'tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle'),
             para_block_reader=read_blankline_block,
             encoding='utf8'):
```

You can pass the reader a word and sentence tokenizer, but for the latter the default already is `nltk.data.LazyLoader('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')`.

For a single string, a tokenizer would be used as follows (explained [here](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html), see section 5 for punkt tokenizer).

```
>>> import nltk.data
>>> text = """
... Punkt knows that the periods in Mr. Smith and Johann S. Bach
... do not mark sentence boundaries.  And sometimes sentences
... can start with non-capitalized words.  i is a good variable
... name.
... """
>>> tokenizer = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')
>>> tokenizer.tokenize(text.strip())
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation. Got it. but how do i output the segmented sentences into a separated txt file?

Comment: ["The NLTK data package includes a pre-trained Punkt tokenizer for
English."](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tokenize/punkt.html)

Answer (score 76):

After some years of figuring out how it works, here's the updated tutorial of

**How to create an NLTK corpus with a directory of textfiles?**

The main idea is to make use of the [**nltk.corpus.reader**](http://nltk.org/api/nltk.corpus.html) package. In the case that you have a directory of textfiles in **English**, it's best to use the [**PlaintextCorpusReader**](http://nltk.org/api/nltk.corpus.reader.html#nltk.corpus.reader.plaintext.PlaintextCorpusReader).

If you have a directory that looks like this:

```
newcorpus/
         file1.txt
         file2.txt
         ...
```

Simply use these lines of code and you can get a corpus:

```
import os
from nltk.corpus.reader.plaintext import PlaintextCorpusReader

corpusdir = 'newcorpus/' # Directory of corpus.

newcorpus = PlaintextCorpusReader(corpusdir, '.*')
```

**NOTE:** that the `PlaintextCorpusReader` will use the default `nltk.tokenize.sent_tokenize()` and `nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize()` to split your texts into sentences and words and these functions are build for English, it may **NOT** work for all languages.

Here's the full code with creation of test textfiles and how to create a corpus with NLTK and how to access the corpus at different levels:

```
import os
from nltk.corpus.reader.plaintext import PlaintextCorpusReader

# Let's create a corpus with 2 texts in different textfile.
txt1 = """This is a foo bar sentence.\nAnd this is the first txtfile in the corpus."""
txt2 = """Are you a foo bar? Yes I am. Possibly, everyone is.\n"""
corpus = [txt1,txt2]

# Make new dir for the corpus.
corpusdir = 'newcorpus/'
if not os.path.isdir(corpusdir):
    os.mkdir(corpusdir)

# Output the files into the directory.
filename = 0
for text in corpus:
    filename+=1
    with open(corpusdir+str(filename)+'.txt','w') as fout:
        print>>fout, text

# Check that our corpus do exist and the files are correct.
assert os.path.isdir(corpusdir)
for infile, text in zip(sorted(os.listdir(corpusdir)),corpus):
    assert open(corpusdir+infile,'r').read().strip() == text.strip()


# Create a new corpus by specifying the parameters
# (1) directory of the new corpus
# (2) the fileids of the corpus
# NOTE: in this case the fileids are simply the filenames.
newcorpus = PlaintextCorpusReader('newcorpus/', '.*')

# Access each file in the corpus.
for infile in sorted(newcorpus.fileids()):
    print infile # The fileids of each file.
    with newcorpus.open(infile) as fin: # Opens the file.
        print fin.read().strip() # Prints the content of the file
print

# Access the plaintext; outputs pure string/basestring.
print newcorpus.raw().strip()
print 

# Access paragraphs in the corpus. (list of list of list of strings)
# NOTE: NLTK automatically calls nltk.tokenize.sent_tokenize and 
#       nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize.
#
# Each element in the outermost list is a paragraph, and
# Each paragraph contains sentence(s), and
# Each sentence contains token(s)
print newcorpus.paras()
print

# To access pargraphs of a specific fileid.
print newcorpus.paras(newcorpus.fileids()[0])

# Access sentences in the corpus. (list of list of strings)
# NOTE: That the texts are flattened into sentences that contains tokens.
print newcorpus.sents()
print

# To access sentences of a specific fileid.
print newcorpus.sents(newcorpus.fileids()[0])

# Access just tokens/words in the corpus. (list of strings)
print newcorpus.words()

# To access tokens of a specific fileid.
print newcorpus.words(newcorpus.fileids()[0])
```

Finally, to read a directory of texts and create an NLTK corpus in another languages, you must first ensure that you have a python-callable **word tokenization** and **sentence tokenization** modules that takes string/basestring input and produces such output:

```
>>> from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
>>> txt1 = """This is a foo bar sentence.\nAnd this is the first txtfile in the corpus."""
>>> sent_tokenize(txt1)
['This is a foo bar sentence.', 'And this is the first txtfile in the corpus.']
>>> word_tokenize(sent_tokenize(txt1)[0])
['This', 'is', 'a', 'foo', 'bar', 'sentence', '.']
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Many languages are supported by default, though.

Comment: If anybody gets an `AttributeError: __exit__` error. Use `open()` instead of `with()`

Comment: Links to documentation are broken now

Comment: Is it possible to build large corpus by using this method?

Answer (score 15):

```py
 >>> import nltk
 >>> from nltk.corpus import PlaintextCorpusReader
 >>> corpus_root = './'
 >>> newcorpus = PlaintextCorpusReader(corpus_root, '.*')
 """
 if the ./ dir contains the file my_corpus.txt, then you 
 can view say all the words it by doing this 
 """
 >>> newcorpus.words('my_corpus.txt')
```

Comment: Shoots some problem for devnagari language.

Answer (score 2):

```
from nltk.corpus.reader.plaintext import PlaintextCorpusReader


filecontent1 = "This is a cow"
filecontent2 = "This is a Dog"

corpusdir = 'nltk_data/'
with open(corpusdir + 'content1.txt', 'w') as text_file:
    text_file.write(filecontent1)
with open(corpusdir + 'content2.txt', 'w') as text_file:
    text_file.write(filecontent2)

text_corpus = PlaintextCorpusReader(corpusdir, ["content1.txt", "content2.txt"])

no_of_words_corpus1 = len(text_corpus.words("content1.txt"))
print(no_of_words_corpus1)
no_of_unique_words_corpus1 = len(set(text_corpus.words("content1.txt")))

no_of_words_corpus2 = len(text_corpus.words("content2.txt"))
no_of_unique_words_corpus2 = len(set(text_corpus.words("content2.txt")))

enter code here
```