# How do I use the book functions (e.g. concoordance) in NLTK?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I am going through this [wonderful tutorial](http://nltk.org/book/ch01.html).

I downloaded a collection called `book`:

```
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.download()
```

and imported texts:

```
>>> from nltk.book import *
*** Introductory Examples for the NLTK Book ***
Loading text1, ..., text9 and sent1, ..., sent9
Type the name of the text or sentence to view it.
Type: 'texts()' or 'sents()' to list the materials.
text1: Moby Dick by Herman Melville 1851
text2: Sense and Sensibility by Jane Austen 1811
```

I can then run commands on these texts:

```
>>> text1.concordance("monstrous")
```

**How can I run these nltk commands on my own dataset? Are these collections the same as the object `book` in python?**

Comment: Do note that `import nltk` might not be necessary when you only need the `nltk.book` functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right that it's quite hard to find the documentation for the `book.py` module. So we have to get our hands dirty and look at the code, (see [here](https://code.google.com/p/nltk/source/browse/trunk/nltk/nltk/book.py?r=8484)). Looking at the `book.py`, to do the conoordance and all the fancy stuff with the book module:

**Firstly** you have to have your raw texts put into nltk's `corpus` class, see [Creating a new corpus with NLTK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951751/creating-a-new-corpus-with-nltk) for more details.

**Secondly** you read the corpus words into the NLTK's `Text` class. Then you could use the functions that you see in http://nltk.org/book/ch01.html

```
from nltk.corpus import PlaintextCorpusReader
from nltk.text import Text

# For example, I create an example text file
text1 = '''
This is a story about a foo bar. Foo likes to go to the bar and his last name is also bar. At home, he kept a lot of gold chocolate bars.
'''
text2 = '''
One day, foo went to the bar in his neighborhood and was shot down by a sheep, a blah blah black sheep.
'''
# Creating the corpus
corpusdir = './mycorpus/' 
with (corpusdir+'text1.txt','w') as fout:
    fout.write(text1)
with (corpusdir+'text2.txt','w') as fout:
    fout.write(text2, fout)

# Read the the example corpus into NLTK's corpus class.
mycorpus = PlaintextCorpusReader(corpusdir, '.*')

# Read the NLTK's corpus into NLTK's text class, 
# where your book-like concoordance search is available
mytext = Text(mycorpus.words())

mytext.concoordance('foo')
```

**NOTE:** you can use other NLTK's CorpusReaders and even specify custom paragraph/sentence/word tokenizers and encoding but now, we'll stick to the default

Comment: Note for others...The helpful sample code above has some (trivial) errors, so don't use it literally or get caught up in understanding every detail.

Comment: Ah there's some really old C like coding style from old Python, let me edit it =)

Answer (score 2):

**Text Analysis with NLTK Cheatsheet from bogs.princeton.edu**
https://blogs.princeton.edu/etc/files/2014/03/Text-Analysis-with-NLTK-Cheatsheet.pdf

**Working with your own texts:**

Open a file for reading

```
file = open('myfile.txt')
```

Make sure you are in the correct directory before starting Python
- or give the full path specification.

Read the file:

```
t = file.read()
```

Tokenize the text:

```
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(t)
```

Convert to NLTK Text object:

```
text = nltk.Text(tokens)
```

Comment: Link leads to Page Not Found error... too bad I was excited to see it.