# how can I put different corpus in NLTK.org?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, corpus

I have few bengali corpora. I want to put them in NLTK.org. I mean I want to keep my corpus in NLTK.org where others corpora are stored. And then want to access them using Nltk tools.
The following link shows how it works for English corpus.
http://nltk.org/data.html
I want to do the same task for bengali corpus. So how to put my corpus in NLTK.org? 
Or is there any other way to access my corpus using NLTk tools? It would be better if I could put my corpus in a sever and from there I could access my corpus using Nltk tools.

Please help me by providing your knowledge about this.

Thanks

Comment: To put a corpus up for downloads `nltk.download()`, you will need to contact the NLTK dev team, see http://nltk.org/team.html. However if you just want to load the corpusreader class in NLTK, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951751/creating-a-new-corpus-with-nltk?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I am going through your links/