# NLTK document classification

Tags: python, text, classification, nltk

In Chapter 6 of the NLTK book, section 2.1 the code calls the movie reviews corpus for document classification. The code in the book is as follows:

```
from nltk.corpus import movie_reviews
documents = [(list(movie_reviews.words(fileid)), category)
         for category in movie_reviews.categories()
         for fileid in movie_reviews.fileids(category)]
 random.shuffle(documents)
```

I have my own dataset comma separated (text, category) between texts of emails and either positive or negative for the category. Can I call .words() on my own file? Also what does the code mean when it calls movie_reviews.categories(). I am having trouble understanding how to structure the data to get it into the form needed by the code. I have look at the individual corpus files but I can't figure out what to do from here. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: hi! have you tried calling `words()` on your file? if so, what happens or what kind of error do you get? what about `categories()`?

Comment: also, have you looked at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/4951751/583834

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`words()` just returns "the given file(s) as a list of words and punctuation symbols" according to [the documentation](http://nltk.org/api/nltk.corpus.reader.html#module-nltk.corpus.reader.aligned). In that respect, you can definitely call `nltk.corpus.words()` on any text file you have.

As for `categories()`, [further down](http://nltk.org/api/nltk.corpus.reader.html#nltk.corpus.reader.CategorizedCorpusReader.categories) in the documentation, it says that it "Return[s] a list of the categories that are defined for this corpus, or for the file(s) if it is given." However, the source for it is a bit more obscure. Notice that different corpora have different ways of indicating their categories. `movie_reviews` does it through directory names, but `abc` and `reuters` have explicit categories in a file. `qc` has the categories in the same file as with the text.

It might take a bit of experimenting with your own data to see if you can replicate this behaviour, but a reasonable first step would be to add a directory containing a subset of your data to `nltk_data/corpora` and to play around with the formats you see in other corpora.