# Is there an established method for tagging your own corpus for supervised learning with NLTK?

Tags: nlp, nltk

I am getting ready to implement supervised named entity recognition on a specialized corpus. That means I need to label raw text by naming the entities. It seems like NLTK things about a [tagged token](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch05.html) as a tuple "consisting of the token and the tag." So my plan is to pull out some random lines from a file, put a word on each line, manually tag the words that are entities to make a csv file -- then read the csv file back in to create token/tag tuples.

Then do something like this (following the [example](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch06.html) from the docs):

```
supervised = []
for line in file:
   token, tag = line.split(",")
   supervised.append(token, tag))

featuresets = [(feature_extractor(token), tag) for (token, tag) in supervised]
```

Is this how NLP practitioners usually do this? Is there a better way to do this? Is there a gold standard? Do people tag entities within the corpus structure? Sort of like this : [Creating a new corpus with NLTK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951751/creating-a-new-corpus-with-nltk)

Comment: You will need about 200K words of tagged data. You will need consistently tagged data. Not generally practical for one person.

Comment: @bmargulies where did that number come from? Nobody ever tags their own corpuses? What I am talking about is simply never done? I am new to NLP and trying to learn this stuff.

Comment: A team of people work for me to build and maintain statistical extractors. Also you will find similar numbers in the good papers about statistical extraction techniques.