# How do I load a *.corpus file into Python?

Tags: python, nlp, corpus

I am trying to load a *.corpus file into Python in order to perform a few NLP tasks. But I do not seem to be able to find any information on how to do this.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951751/creating-a-new-corpus-with-nltk

Answer (score 0):

The [NLTK](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/wiki) library provides a [Corpus module](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.corpus.html), which seems to be able to read these files.