# NLTK- Python -Cannot import a new corpus

Tags: python-3.x, nltk

I am new to nltk. I am trying to import a new NLTK- corpus. I have added it on path C:\nltk_data\corpora. Import is working for an existing copora like brown and gutenberg. But when I am importing a new corpus using the same command, it is throwing an error:

> cannot import name 'newcorpus'.

Code:

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import newcorpus
```

Python version 3.5.2 32 bit

NLTK version 3.2.1 32 bit

**Question**

Does anyone know how to resolve this error?

Comment: Duplicate of - http://stackoverflow.com/q/4951751/1168680 ??

Comment: Point 1.9 - Loading your own Corpus - http://www.nltk.org/book/ch02.html , http://www.nltk.org/howto/corpus.html#corpus-reader-classes, http://stackoverflow.com/a/20922201/1168680