# How to call my own corpora and use it with NLTK

Tags: python, import, nltk, corpus

I've learned how to create my own corpus thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951751/creating-a-new-corpus-with-nltk). I now want to start using the NLTK tools to analyse my own .txt files.

I've been follow [this youtube-playlist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TKAXDqoG2dc&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDf2JswnfiGkliBInZnIC4HL&index=9), which I've been finding very educational. In (the linked) part 9, at 6:25, he imports a corpus from NLTKs own collection, and starts meddling with it using the NLTK commands (such as tokenize, etc.).

This is what I'm having trouble with. After I've created a path to my own corpus (corpus_root in the above-mentioned post), how do I import it and start using the simple NLTK commands that this guy teaches? Hopefully the question is as dumb and easy as I think it is, I'm just lost at the moment.

If anyone wants me to clarify, I'd be happy to.

Thanks.