# How can I load my txt corpora using NLTK?

Tags: python-3.x, nltk

I'm really new to python and I'm experiencing some issues related to loading my corpus with NLTK. My version is 3.6.3 and I installed NLTK using pip install,I have tested NLTK with short sentences and it has worked so far, but I cannot use my own .txt corpora that is stored in my pc. I have tried something like this:

```
import codecs
import nltk

text = codecs.open('myfilename.txt','r','utf-8')
```

But then I get all kinds of error. I think it has something to do with my file location but I can't find an nltk_data anywhere. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you should describe your `all kinds of errors`. but in general you are going about write, once opening the file you can use `import nltk; nltk.Text(text.split())`

Comment: Your code snippet usefully shows that the problem is unrelated to the nltk; the file you are trying to read is not UTF-8 encoded. Try "latin-1"? (Better yet: Find out the correct encoding, and use that.)

Comment: After figuring where your file is exactly and its encoding, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951751/creating-a-new-corpus-with-nltk