# Extract author names in the PDF using Python

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, pypdf, pdf-extraction

I have multiple PDF files where I need to extract the author names. I need to extract the author names only from the first page of the PDF file and ignore all the other pages.

I have multiple PDF files which the same format where I need to extract the author names.

Here is the link for PDF
[pdf file](https://purple-katuscha-96.tiiny.site)

Below is the image where the first page of PDF looks like

[image]

I need to extract the author names which is in bold color. I am using the below code to extract

```
import PyPDF2
import re
file = 'pdf_file'
reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(file)
page = reader.pages[0]
pdf_text_from_paper = page.extract_text()
emails_pattern  = r"\{([^}]+)\}"
email_matches = re.findall(emails_pattern, pdf_text_from_paper)
```

I could able to extract the emails but not the names. Can anyone tell on how to extract the names?

Comment: What are you trying to extract?

Comment: I am collecting these author names so that I can use these for ML training

Comment: PyPDF2 is deprecated. Use pypdf (I'm the maintainer of both)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not certain that this will work for all of your pdfs, but this at least works for the one you linked to in your question and if they are all the same format then it could work on the others as well.:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'\s{4}(?!Introduction)(\w+\s\w*?\.?\s?\w*?)\s{2}')
matches = pattern.findall(page)
print(matches)
```

output

```
['Jiaheng Xie', 'Xiao Liu', 'Daniel Dajun Zeng', 'Xiao Fang']
```

### EDIT

This pattern works on both pdfs you linked to.

```
pattern = re.compile(r'1\s+?(\w+\s\w*?\.?\s?\w*?)\s*?\n|\{\w+?.*?@.*?\}\s+?(\w+\s\w*?\.?\s?\w*?)\s*?\n')
for doc in ["document1.pdf", "document2.pdf"]:
    reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(doc)
    page = reader.pages[0]
    text = page.extract_text()
    matches = pattern.findall(text)
    print([j for i in matches for j in i if j])
```

OUTPUT:

```
['Jiaheng Xie', 'Xiao Liu', 'Daniel Dajun Zeng', 'Xiao Fang']
['Honglin Deng', 'Weiquan W ang', 'Siyuan Li', 'Kai H. Lim']
```

Comment: I'm certain that this will only work for some PDFs :-)

Comment: The same code is not working for this pdf: https://purple-katuscha-96.tiiny.site

Comment: How do you use this word "Introduction"? Is this word appeared in pdf?

Comment: Yes... It also matched the pattern so that excluded it from the list of matches.

Comment: @merkle  Did you see the edit?

Answer (score 0):

PDF files have a metadata field. It might not be filled, but maybe you're lucky sometimes:

```py
from pypdf import PdfReader

reader = PdfReader("example.pdf")
print(reader.metadata.author)
```

See the [pypdf docs on metadata](https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/metadata.html)

If the authors names are not set in the metadata field, you need machine learning to make this work for a more general case. The sub-field is called [Natural Language Processing (NLP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing). You would start by extracting the text:

```py
from pypdf import PdfReader

reader = PdfReader("example.pdf")
text = ""

# potentially you only want the first page, but it's
# not guaranteed that the authors will always be on
# the first page.
for page in reader.pages:
    text += page.extract_text() + "\n"
```

Then you can ignore the PDF parts. It's only about recognizing the right parts of the text. That is a different question, e.g.:

- [How to extract name from string using nltk](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47123094/562769)
- [Extract Named Entities using SpaCy and python lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65527427/562769)
- Or anything in [named-entity-extraction](/questions/tagged/named-entity-extraction)

Comment: This is not working Martin

Comment: It might have an empty result for some PDFs (if the PDF creator didn't set that metadata field), but I can assure you it is working in general.

Comment: The PDF creator haven't set the metadata field. Is there any way to get the author names?

Comment: Just by parsing the content then. And that is very unlikely to work well with simple regexes. That is rather a machine learning task. I'll expand my answer a little bit.

Comment: Here is the link for pdf: https://purple-katuscha-96.tiiny.site

Answer (score 0):

Usually the simplest when a page has a known layout is to export the plain text to a file in fixed area[s].

Here using console (without file redirection) which you can do for extracting the area with four names. However, you could extract four separate entries of name only into each file line.

The problem then is that it's 4 this time, but could be 3 or 2 or 1, thus different extractors would need different profiles, which can be run in parallel then auto-select the best run.

[image]

In this case by exclude lines with email symbol `@` and exclude UNI or SCHOOL etc.

[image]

```
pdftotext -f 1 -l 1 -nopgbrk -layout -margint 190 -marginb 400 "document (Author).pdf" -|findstr /i /v "@ uni school"
```

If you want the email the keep the `@`:

[image]

Once you have your clean extraction then it's easier to second process with regex or simpler means as the lines are now split.