# Is it possible to use the NLTK concordance feature for Emoji?

Tags: python, nltk

I have successfully used the `concordance()` method in NLTK with **my own text file** that I read in through the Gutenberg Corpus:

```
    bom = open('sentences-with-emoji.txt')
    from nltk.text import Text
    bom = Text(nltk.corpus.gutenberg.words('/my-own-text-file.txt'))
    bom.concordance('messiah')
```

I say "through" because the `concordance()` method only reads words through the specified corpus, which is the Gutenberg. The Gutenberg corpus doesn't have emoji in it. So when I try a different file containing emoji like this:

```
    bom = open('sentences-with-emoji.txt’)
    from nltk.text import Text
    bom = Text(nltk.corpus.gutenberg.words('/sentences-with-emoji.txt'))
    bom.concordance('')
```

I get the response:

`No matches`

Do I have to create an annotated corpus (using the process here: [Creating a new corpus with NLTK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951751/creating-a-new-corpus-with-nltk))  with my `/sentences-with-emoji.txt` file in order to use the `concordance()` method with emoji?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nltk.text` requires you to pass a list of tokens. Also, you don't have to create a new corpus or make the extra roundtrip through `gutenberg.words`. It is sufficient to load and tokenize a raw text file.

```
# raw = open('sentences-with-emoji.txt').read()
raw = 'word  word'
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(raw)

text = Text(tokens)
text.concordance('')

Displaying 1 of 1 matches:
                                  word  word
```

Comment: So I can replicate what you did above, however, when I try to access an emoji in the file I get `no matches`.  Any ideas how to do be able to get a concordance of emoji from a file (instead of a variable)?

Comment: @matt_07734 can you update the question with the way you are trying to load the file?

Comment: @matt_07734 you have to tokenize your raw text string first. Afterwards pass this list of tokens to the Text() constructor

Comment: Your response works as posted. I was using the wrong text file... Silly mistake on my part. Thanks for the answer though!